# Can the Outlook 2010 Custom View drop-down menu be made to look like the Outlook 2007Custom View drop-down menu?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am migrating from Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2010. One reason I've avoided this upgrade is that I use different custom views to sort and prioritize Tasks, and I find switching between these views in Outlook 2010 to be very cumbersome (see linked photos below).

Outlook 2007 has both a convenient [side-bar with a list of all of the views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIp00.jpg) and a [searchable drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp2tk.jpg) of all views. The searchable drop-down menu (called "Current View") is available in the "Customize" menu on the "Commands" tab under the ["Advanced" category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbfp7.jpg).

Outlook 2010 uses [icons instead of lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0eDY.jpg) when displaying the [names of different views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AcXw.jpg). I've searched through the [customization options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nyF.jpg) but have not found anything like the drop-down list in Outlook 2007. **Does such a menu exist in Outlook 2010?** Alternatively, does Outlook 2016 have this feature? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, such a drop-down combobox doesn't exist in Outlook 2010-2016. But it can be implemented by programming the Outlook add-in.

Creating the addin is not that hard. Start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook. And this is what you need to add to your ribbon customization: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906352(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Bummer. Thanks. How hard is it to learn to program an Outlook add-in? I have been teaching myself to program in R, and I've written a few Unix and Windows scripts over the years.

Comment: @Josh updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with thims that there is no option available in Outlook to see such a view in neither Outlook 2010 nor Outlook 2016. If you have more concerns on this feature, you may submit your suggestion to the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).